# filtered data not refreshing in angular

Tags: angular, ionic3, ionic4

I am trying to filter an array of object on basis on last_name.

```
 filterItems(searchTerm) {
    return this.EmpData.filter(emp => {
      return emp.lastName.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) > -1 || driver.firstName.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) > -1;
    });
  }
```

and in html template

```
 <ion-list *ngIf="showEmpList">
                <ion-item *ngFor="let item of EmpData" button (click)="selectEmp(item.lastName)">
                    <ion-label>{{item.lastName}}, {{item.middle}}, {{item.firstName}}</ion-label>
                </ion-item>
     </ion-list>
```

this is working when i am typing name in search box but when i am deleting characters from name that result is not refreshing with new data.
for example-
i have data=`[{name:'Amir','age':28},{name:'AAmir', age:26},{name:'AAAmir', age:30}]`
*now i if put AA in search box it will display last two result and if i put AAA then it will display only last emp data now if i delete two or more characters from input field suppose new input is A then result is displaying as only last employee data*

please help.Thanks in advance

Comment: can you provide a stackblitz?

Comment: see this :- https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-gqingy. It works.

Comment: Hi Akash when i am putting static data it is working fine for me but when i am trying to fetch data from api in that case getting this issue

Comment: it should work same way, until you have some other kind of code, provide a stackblitz?

Comment: thanks your example solved my issue. problem was that i did not store filtered data in new var in that case my orignal array was filered hence i was not getting desired result. Thanks man. you can put link in answer so that i can accept.

Comment: posted below, happy to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be your filtered array is pointing to same array as original, thats why you are altering original Array. I have done some code for same :-

Stackblitz URL :-  https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-gqingy

HTML :-

```
 <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="filterText" (ngModelChange)="filterValues()"/>

 <ion-list>
                <ion-item *ngFor="let item of filteredData" button (click)="selectEmp(item.lastName)">
                    <ion-label>{{item.name}}, {{item.age}}</ion-label>
                </ion-item>
     </ion-list>
```

TS :-

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

import { TabsPage } from '../pages/tabs/tabs';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  rootPage:any = TabsPage;
  EmpData = [{name:'Amir',age:28},{name:'AAmir', age:26},{name:'AAAmir', age:30}];
  filteredData = [{name:'Amir',age:28},{name:'AAmir', age:26},{name:'AAAmir', age:30}];
  public filterText: string = '';
  constructor(platform: Platform) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.

    });
  }

  public filterValues() {
    this.filteredData = this.EmpData.filter((data) => data.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.filterText? this.filterText.toLowerCase():''));
  }
}
```